# After calling setSurface(null) and setSurface(surface) to a MediaPlayer, it always returns the same value with getCurrentPosition() on Android 6.0

Tags: android

I encountered a problem while trying MediaPlayer with TextureView on Android 6.0.  Does anyone have an idea on that?

### Environment

- Nexus 7 2013
- Android 6.0.1

### Code to Reproduce

(For the entire app code, see https://gist.github.com/hkurokawa/f18857ae695f0fdee9ab)

A snippet of the code of the Activity, I believe, related to the issue is as following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() start");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    videoView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    videoView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    try {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
        mp.prepare();
        this.mp = mp;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() end");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume() start");
    super.onResume();
    setupVideo(videoView.getSurfaceTexture());
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume() end");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause() start");
    super.onPause();
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
    }
    mp.setOnErrorListener(null);
    mp.setSurface(null);
    handler.removeCallbacks(logCurrentPosition);
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause() end");
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureAvailable() start");
    setupVideo(surface);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureAvailable() end");
}

private void setupVideo(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    Log.i(TAG, "setupVideo() start");
    if (surface == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setupVideo() canceled");
        return;
    }
    mp.setSurface(new Surface(surface));

    mp.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred while playing a video: " + what + ", " + extra);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mp.start();
    handler.postDelayed(logCurrentPosition, 1000);
    Log.i(TAG, "setupVideo() end");
}
```

### Result

- After pressing the power button to make the app suspend and then restore it with pressing the button again, `mp.getCurrentPosition()` keeps returning a fixed value even though the video is being played (but with no sound)

The output of logcat is like this:

```
12-22 20:14:20.001 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: onPause() start
12-22 20:14:20.053 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: onPause() end
12-22 20:14:20.190 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: onResume() start
12-22 20:14:20.190 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: setupVideo() start
12-22 20:14:20.197 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: setupVideo() end
12-22 20:14:20.197 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: onResume() end
12-22 20:14:21.199 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: Current position: 493
12-22 20:14:22.199 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: Current position: 493
12-22 20:14:23.200 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: Current position: 493
12-22 20:14:24.201 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: Current position: 493
12-22 20:14:25.202 31733-31733/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample I/com.example.hiroshikurokawa.videosample.MainActivity: Current position: 493
```

### Expected Result

- After the restore, the video continues to play and `mp.getCurrentPosition()` returns the correct value.

### Remarks

- As far as I tried with some devices, it seems this problem only occurs on Android 6.0.  Did not occur on Android 5.1 or 4.4.

### Background

It might be better to describe why I would like this code work. Currently, I am trying to cache MediaPlayer instance to avoid loading the same video many times. To reuse MediaPlayer instance, I have to clear the reference to a `Surface` at `onPause()` and re-set the surface at `onResume()` so that it does not cause memory-leak. If my assumption is wrong, please let me know.

Thanks,